# python access selective files with glob module

Tags: python

I have a collection of binary files which have names as so:

```
d010-recomb.bin
d011-recomb.bin
.............
.............
.............
d100-recomb.bin
```

Using the python glob module, i can access all the files in a folder and can do further processing with these files:

```
import glob
binary = sorted(glob.glob('C:/Users/Desktop/bin/*.bin'))
```

I can also use some criteria for the files that I want to access:

FOr example if I use the following code then I will gain access to all the files from d010-recomb.bin to d019-recomb.bin

```
binary = sorted(glob.glob('C:/Users/Desktop/bin/d01*.bin'))
```

But using this criteria I can't get access to files such as d015 to d025.

**Please** tell me what I can do to gain access to these files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the list afterwards; either turn the filename portion to an `int` or create a range of strings that are to be included:

```
included = {'d{:03d}'.format(i) for i in range(15, 26)}  # a set

binary = sorted(f for f in glob.glob('C:/Users/Desktop/bin/*.bin') if f[21:25] in included)
```

The above code generates the strings `'d015'`  through to `'d025'` as a set of strings for fast membership testing, then tests the first 4 characters of each file against that set; because `glob()` returns whole filenames we slice off the path for that to work.

For variable paths, I'd store the slice offset, for speed, based on the path:

```
pattern = 'C:/Users/Desktop/bin/*.bin'
included = {'d{:03d}'.format(i) for i in range(15, 26)}  # a set
offset = len(os.path.dirname(pattern)) + 1

binary = sorted(f for f in glob.glob(pattern) if f[offset:offset + 4] in included)
```

Demo of the latter:

```
$ mkdir test
$ touch test/d014-recomb.bin
$ touch test/d015-recomb.bin
$ touch test/d017-recomb.bin
$ touch test/d018-recomb.bin
$ fg
bin/python2.7
>>> import os, glob
>>> pattern = '/tmp/stackoverflow/test/*.bin'
>>> included = {'d{:03d}'.format(i) for i in range(15, 26)}  # a set
>>> offset = len(os.path.dirname(pattern)) + 1
>>> sorted(f for f in glob.glob(pattern) if f[offset:offset + 4] in included)
['/tmp/stackoverflow/test/d015-recomb.bin', '/tmp/stackoverflow/test/d017-recomb.bin', '/tmp/stackoverflow/test/d018-recomb.bin']
```

Comment: The `f[21:25]` is pretty  case-specific and won't work for different paths.
How about `if os.path.basename(f).split('.')[0] in included`? This should be independent from the path before the filename.

Comment: @MikeMüller: it would be; but the slice is faster. You could store the offset in a variable.

Comment: Hi Martijn, thank you for your answer. I am trying to understand your code. specially the second and last line. when I run the code, it says KeyError: '03d'. Could you please explain a bit as i am not very good at it. The answer from glglgl is working though. But I would like to understand your coding. Thanks again.

Comment: @user2095624: That was my fault, actually; updated the `.format()` template to work properly. Mea Culpa!

Answer (score 1):

You can either filter list, using:

```python
def filter_path(path,l,r):
    i = int(os.path.basename(path)[1:4])
    if (i >= l) and (i <= r):
        return True
    return False

result = [i for i in binary if filter_path(i,19,31)]
```

If you are 100% confident about number of elements in directory, you can:

```python
result = binary[19:30]
```

Or once you have data sorted, you may find the *first index* and the *last index* and [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/in-python-how-do-i-find-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it)[[2]](http://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```python
l = binary.find('C:/Users/Desktop/bin/d015.bin')
r = binary.find('C:/Users/Desktop/bin/d023.bin')
result = binary[l:r+1]
```

Comment: The `r` result will not be included; end points are exclusive when slicing.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to add this restriction manually, as it cannot be accomplished by a glob pattern.

If you exactly know how the file names are built, you could do

```
import os
for i in range(19, 34): # 19 to 33
    filename = "d%03d-recomb.bin" % i
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join('C:/Users/Desktop/bin', filename)):
        print filename
```

Comment: What if not all of those files are present?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ouch! Thought about it and forgot it again. Added test. Thanks!